# How to order date based on a column in databse with most recent date on top

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 6 different tables in my database with a column 'created_at' in all the 6 tables. I want to order my response such that most recent post comes at top. I am using orderBy('created_at') but it is returning the post in wrong order. I have this column 'created_at' with type 'timestamp' in my database. It is returning the post in this order 1st- 06 Oct 2019,2nd-07 Oct 2019, 3rd-23 Sept 2019, 4th-26 Sept 2019, 5th-27 Sept 2019 and so on. Here is my code:-

```
public function wsUserActivity(){
    $request = Input::all();
    try {
        $user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $no=isset($request['page_number'])?$request['page_number']:0;
        $nos=isset($request['count'])?$request['count']:10;
        $skp=$no*$nos;
        $array_json_return = array('status' => '1','msg' => 'Success');


        $u_activity = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select(DB::raw('"article" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');




        $u_meetup = DB::table('mst_meetup as meetup')
        ->select(DB::raw('"meetup" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image' )
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');



        $u_question = array();
        $u_question = DB::table('mst_question as question')
        ->select(DB::raw('"question" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');


        $u_job = array();
        $u_job = DB::table('mst_job as job')
        ->select(DB::raw('"job" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');



        $u_education = array();
        $u_education = DB::table('mst_education as education')
        ->select(DB::raw('"education" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');


        $u_activity= DB::table('mst_event as event')
        ->select(DB::raw('"event" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image' )
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->union($u_article)->union($u_question)->union($u_meetup)->union($u_job)->union($u_education)
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->skip($skp)
        ->take($nos)
        ->get();

        if (count($u_activity)>0){
            foreach ($u_activity as $key => $value){
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_activity[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").$value->type.'_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_activity[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-'.$value->type.  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }



        $array_json_return['u_activity'] = $u_activity;


    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $array_json_return = $this->api_default_fail_response(__function__, $e);
    }

    echo json_encode($array_json_return);
}
```

Comment: Your `ORDER By` needs to be DESCending instead of the default ascending.

Comment: I think its a little more complected than adding `DESC` to the query. I think the problem lies in the `UNION` and `DATE_FORMAT(created_at` It is indeed ordering by the created at column, just not as a date.  Instead I think it is sorting it as a string.  The simplest answer would be to try removing the DATE_FORMAT from all of the UNION subjects and then do the formatting in PHP.  If you want to do it in SQL, you will need to put the `$u_education` in the FROM clause of another SELECT, and do the DATE_FORMAT in this outer most query.

Comment: I can't remove DATE_FORMAT is there any other method to order it

Comment: I don't understand. Kindly send it corrected in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function wsUserActivity(){
    $request = Input::all();
    try {
        $user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $no=isset($request['page_number'])?$request['page_number']:0;
        $nos=isset($request['count'])?$request['count']:10;
        $skp=$no*$nos;
        $array_json_return = array('status' => '1','msg' => 'Success');


        $u_activity = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select(DB::raw('"article" as type'),'id','title',  'created_at',  'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');




        $u_meetup = DB::table('mst_meetup as meetup')
        ->select(DB::raw('"meetup" as type'),'id','title', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image' )
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');



        $u_question = array();
        $u_question = DB::table('mst_question as question')
        ->select(DB::raw('"question" as type'),'id','title', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');


        $u_job = array();
        $u_job = DB::table('mst_job as job')
        ->select(DB::raw('"job" as type'),'id','title','created_at',  'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');



        $u_education = array();
        $u_education = DB::table('mst_education as education')
        ->select(DB::raw('"education" as type'),'id','title',  'created_at', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');


        $u_activity= DB::table('mst_event as event')
        ->select(DB::raw('"event" as type'),'id','title',  'created_at',  'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image' )
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->union($u_article)->union($u_question)->union($u_meetup)->union($u_job)->union($u_education)
        ->skip($skp)
        ->take($nos)
        ->latest()
        ->get();

        if (count($u_activity)>0){
            foreach ($u_activity as $key => $value){
                $u_activity[$key]->created_at = DATE_FORMAT(new \DateTime($value->created_at), "d M Y");
                $u_activity[$key]->updated_at = DATE_FORMAT(new \DateTime($value->updated_at), "d M Y");
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)){
                $u_activity[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").$value->type.'_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_activity[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-'.$value->type.  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }



        $array_json_return['u_activity'] = $u_activity;


    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $array_json_return = $this->api_default_fail_response(__function__, $e);
    }

    echo json_encode($array_json_return);
}
```